Add dynamic html property to ChildComponent
I want to add a dynamic html property to my ChildComponent in the html, like hits:
<child-component test={{ variable }}></child.component>

I dont want to use it as an input just need it in the html for testing.
I tried the above but when I do this I get an error:
"Can't bind to 'test' since it isn't a known property"

Thanks!

You can make use of attr to just create a attribute!
<child-component [attr.test]="variable"></child.component>


If you childComponent has such property, use property-binding:
<child-component [property]="expression or variable you need to test"></child.component>

If your childComponent doesn't have "test" property, so you may need to use attribute
<child-component [attr.test]="variable"></child.component>

